# C++ Metaprogramming sum of two types

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have a class like this

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
typedef T value_type
...
};
```

I would like to write a function that needs to deal with different `Matrix<T>` types but also with arithmetic types (that is why I cannot use `Matrix<T1>` and `Matrix<T2>` as template arguments). Inside the function I need a `Matrix` that has the correct type, if I pass `Matrix<T3>` and `Matrix<T4>` for `a` and `b` then the type of the `Matrix C` should be whatever `T3 + T4` returns (`T3` and `T4` are arithmetic types).

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto add(T1&& a, T2&& b);
Matrix<decltype(a(0,0) + b(0,0))> C{}; // This works, but I am sure there is a nicer solution
```

I found one way to do it but I am sure that it is possible to work directly with the types.
I tried something like

```cpp
Matrix<decltype(remove_cvref_t<T1>::value_type + remove_cvref_t<T2>::value_type) C;
```

The idea is to strip off any possible references and access the type of the `Matrix` via `::value_type`. I also tried to sprinkle in some `typename`s but without success.

Comment: the `decltype` solution is the one I would use.  If you need that type more then once you can do at the beginning `using common_t = decltype(a(0,0) + b(0,0));` to get an alias for the common type.

Comment: The “nicer solution” you mention might be `std::declval`. BTW, I’d call the function `operator +` instead of `add`. If you need to unwrap the `Matrix` template and get its constituent types, you can use multiple levels of templates, like so: `template<template<typename ...> class M1, template<typename ...> class M2, typename T1, typename T2> auto operator +(M1<T1>&& a, M2<T2>&& b) -> ReturnType { ... }` As for the `ReturnType`, that may be a `Matrix<decltype(declval<T1>() + declval<T2>())>` or maybe a `decltype(declval<M1<T1>>() + declval<M2<T2>>())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to work directly with the types, but you can use [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) - a function which returns whatever type you want - to "convert" a type to a value:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto add(T1&& a, T2&& b) {
    Matrix<decltype(
        std::declval<remove_cvref_t<T1>::value_type>()
        + std::declval<remove_cvref_t<T2>::value_type>()
    )> C;
    ...
}
```

It's still ugly. If all your matrices have the `(0,0)` operator then you might find that less ugly, and there's nothing wrong with using it; if you absolutely do need `value_type` as opposed to whatever `(0,0)` returns, then you can use `std::declval`.

`std::declval` can't be called for real - its only purpose is to be used in expressions that don't actually get evaluated, like inside `decltype` or `noexcept`.

Comment: Thanks, the `declval` solution works fine! I needed to add a `typename` before each of the `remove_cvref_t<...>` however (noted here for documentation)

Comment: @Urwald ah yes, that's because `remove_cvref_t<T1>::value_type` is a dependent name and nothing to do with `declval` itself